# Set several "ChangeLogFile" value in liquibase.properties

Tags: database, liquibase

I want to pass several changelogfile in liquibase.properties to make sure all the files are applied in the order I like as well as I could simply drop one file if that part of the change was not suitable.
I have this liquibase.properties file now:

```
driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath: mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar
url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test_db_migration;user=sa;password=Password1
changeLogFile: Changelogs/db.tables.part1.sql
```

Is there any way I can pass two .sql file address in ChangeLogFile attribute?

Comment: Have you seen liquibase [best practices](https://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html)? You can define a master changelog file and put that into your properties and from the master refer to multiple other files...

Comment: Yes @Jens, right. This ChangeLogFile tag is developed to address the main file which can contain several files. Thanks for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

liquibase handle xml/yml file format - not directly sql file format.

in the xml grammar, you can include xml files to gather many changesets together.

you can also include sql in changeset if you want.

hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks Eric. In fact, Liquibase supports SQL file directly and I tested this in my code. I wanted to find a way to have several changeLogFile values. I could not find any file separator for this tag (changeLogFile) in liquibase documentation.

Comment: you can create un master changeLogFile that includes all your changeLogFile to achieve that.